# How do I generate build-info.properties in the IntelliJ "out" directory on debug/run for a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-actuator

In my build.gradle, I have added spring build info:

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = "${springBootMainClass}"

    buildInfo() {
        additionalProperties = [
                name: "${appName}",
                version: "${version}-${buildNumber}",
                time: buildTime()
        ]
    }
}

def buildTime() {
    final dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
    dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT')
    dateFormat.format(new Date())
}
```

When I run from the command line, this correctly adds the `/META-INF/build-info.properties` file into `/build/resources/main` so that the `"/info"` endpoint shows the build information in JSON.

When I run from IntelliJ's run/debug button, IntelliJ does *not* use the `/build` directory but instead uses the `/out` directory and also does not run that gradle task, so the `/info` endpoint has empty JSON.

How can I make it generate that file and put it in the `/out` directory?

Comment: Please enable **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** option in Settings (preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner tab. Does it help? The other workaround is to change the Run/Debug Configuration "before launch task" from 'Build' to 'Run Gradle task "build"'.

Comment: @andrey Setting the **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** option worked for me. Please consider submitting this as the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Enable **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** option in Settings (Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | [Runner](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/runner.html) tab.

In latest IDE versions set **Gradle** for the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | [Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-settings.html) | **Build and run using** option.

Comment: I'm getting a new issue with this. Using this setting, it does not see any changes to my classes (when I restart the run/debug configuration). Even doing rebuild project, or `.gradlew clean` at the command line do not make it see the changes in the code. How do i make it actually rebuild everything?

Comment: When delegate option is used IDE should use Gradle compiler output directories for compiled classes. You can double check it by deleting all output directories in project (e.g. IDE's default `out` and Gradle's `build`) and rebuild the project via Build | Rebuild project action and check that only gradle ouptut directory was created. Then check that the classes are actually updated in the Gradle's compiler output directory.

Comment: Wait how is this accepted? It fundamentally changes how the IDE works, I don't want to do this. Is there another workaround?

Comment: there is no runner tab  under Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle  in intellJ

Comment: @milosmns it also is considerably slower

Answer (score 16):

For anyone else with this problem in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (where the option @Andrey said does not exist), you just have to add a `Run Maven Goal` before launch. This will execute the goal of the plugin: `spring-boot:build-info` before build and run

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I have exactly the same need, and I don't want to use "delegate IDE build/run action to Gradle" for different (good) reasons.

In my case I don't need that file `/META-INF/build-info.properties` to be up-to-date in IDEA during develop phase, I just need this file to be available in the "run" classpath (under `/out/...`), else Spring won't be able to create and inject the `BuildProperties` bean when launching my app from IDEA run/debug tool.

So here is a simple solution if your are also in my case:

1. create a dummy "dev" (or "snapshot") version of the build-info.properties in the main resources directory  ( `src/main/resources/META-INF/build-info.properties` )

   #DO NOT EDIT (will be overriden by Spring boot plugin )
   build.time=2019-05-07T11:32:31.581Z
   build.artifact=myapp
   build.group=org.mycompany
   build.name=myapp
   build.version=dev

This dev version will be automatically copied into IDEA `/out/production/resources` directory when building project from IDEA

2. Create a task dependency between `bootBuildInfo` task and `processResources` tasks, to make sure that Spring boot plugin will override the "dev" version with up-to-date version when building the app jar:

   bootBuildInfo.mustRunAfter processResources

This way, SpringBoot gradle plugin will override the file copied from sources by `processResources` task, with its auto-generated up-to-date file.

**EDIT 2020-10**

As Dmitry warned in comment below, this solution will break Gradle incremental build, as both `processResources` and `bootBuildInfo` tasks share the same output file `build-info.properties`. To avoid that, we can add exclusion in the `processResources` to filter out this file, when we detect that tasks graph contains `bootBuildInfo`  tasks

```
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    if (it.allTasks.any {it.name == "bootBuildInfo"}) {
        processResources {
            exclude("META-INF/build-info.properties")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you create the task dependency? And will the overwrite still occur when run on production? Or will your file be used outside IntelliJ?

Comment: The dependency is created in your project `build.gradle` below `springBoot { }` configuration block for example. I guess that in Production you use the Springboot jar , produced by SpringBoot/gradle build:  so YES, the jar will contain the up-to-date version of the file generated by SpringBoot plugin.  the "dev" version of this file in only used for running app within IDEA

Comment: Also, don't forget to configure Gradle as explained at [Filtering runtime classpath](https://guides.gradle.org/using-build-cache/#filter_runtime_classpath). So that it ignores the "change" in `build-info.properties`. Otherwise, the Gradle build-cache will "stop working" as you would expect. For instance, it will rerun all the tests even if they haven't changed but the `build-info.properties` file has "changed" if the so-called "dev" version gets compared to the generated one which is found on the classpath, namely `build/resources/main/META-INF/build-info.properties` (the default one)

Comment: Part 1 of your solution works fine for me, but how do I force the task to overwrite the dummy files in a maven project? <goal>repackage</goal> does not work