# git.properties is not visible for spring boot autoconfigure

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I use gradle plugin to generate `git.properties`:

```
id 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties' version '2.2.0'
```

It generates

```
/resources/main/git.properties
```

However when `GitResourceAvailableCondition` is evaluated in `spring-boot-autoconfigure` then

`ResourceLoader` indicates that `classpath:git.properties` does not exist.

How I can point to my resource in order to make it visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when running from Idea plugin is not executed - I've changed configuration in Idea to use gradle https://stackoverflow.com/a/48060458/296427 and it works like a charm